# Apple Appstore keywords – Syntax, stemming & matching rules

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I'm not hoping for clues on picking key words, there are [guides about that](http://www.bluecloudsolutions.com/blog/app-store-keywords-choose-terms/) already.

I'm hoping to get a decisive idea, with a reference to documentation or statements from Apple of:

- **The correct keyword list syntax.**
- **How they are employed for matching in Apple's back end.**

For example:

- Should they be comma delineated: "ham,chips,beans"?
- Or space delineated: "ham chips beans"?
- Or comma and space: "ham, chips, beans"?

If customers might search for me by a phrase, such as "hungry cat", should I include "hungry, cat, hungry cat, hungry-cat"? Or is "hungry cat" sufficient?

I believe it's not necessary to add plural forms: "cat**s**" isn't needed, provided I have "*cat*". But what about other stemming? If people search for "eat**ing** cats", is "*eat*, cat" in my search terms enough?

Thanks.

---

There are two votes to close stating this question is "opinion based". I've adjusted the question to make it clear that I am not looking for opinion, but statements or documentation from Apple.

Comment: http://www.hpique.com/2013/01/app-store-keywords-checklist-21-tips-to-work-around-apples-horrible-search/

Comment: I can't speak for those that have voted to close based on it being "opinion based", but I would (if I could) vote to close on the fact that this question has nothing to do with programming. Reference: [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank you @SlyRaskal, that's good feedback! I've read help link and I think you're right. I suppose I think of everything I do day-to-day as programming and so appropriate to S.O., but that that's a mistake.

Comment: Huh – self delete is discouraged because the question has an answer. So I'll leave it. Perhaps it'll be a lesson to others :-)

Comment: I realize now this is indeed an off-topic question that probably should be removed, I shouldn't have answered. :p